# why there are multiple js files generated by webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm new to React and webpack, just some questions on js files generated by webpack. I always thought webpack will get all the dependencies js into a single `bundle.js` file, but when I check my browser, I see there are actually three files which are:

`0.chunk.js`
`bundle.js`
`main.chunk.js`

Below is my questions:

Q1-Why not webpack just get everything and bundle them into a single `bundle.js` file?

Q2-what's the purpose of `0.chunk.js`, `main.chunk.js`?

Q3-Who inserts the script elements for each js file in the index.html file, webpack, or loader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1-Why isn't webpack bundling everything into a single `bundle.js` file**

Generating chunks is an opt-in feature. Webpack doesn't generate chunks by default. The reason why generating chunks might be useful is explained in Q2.

**Q2-What's the purpose of `0.chunk.js`, `main.chunk.js`**

A chunk is a separate file consisting of common modules shared between multiple entry points. Separating these common modules from bundles allows for those chunks to be loaded once initially and stored in the cache for later use.

**Q3-Who inserts the script elements for each .js file in the index.html file, Webpack or loader?**

Webpack. Loaders are used to pack any non-javascript resource and help Webpack compile and bundle those non-javascript resources as Webpack itself only understands javascript. Loaders work at their files during or before the bundle is generated.

Comment: another question for loaders, so what does `style-loader` do? my understanding is `style-loader` creates js code that manipulate DOM API to change the style, which means it is actually `style-loader` that produces js code sometimes?

Comment: style-loader actually injects CSS using the <style> tag into your .html file. It does not create js code. It's mostly used together with css-loader which will bundle your .css files.

Comment: below is quoted  from my textbook, I think the author means style-loader create js code:The loaders added to the project deal with CSS by adding JavaScript code that is executed when the contents of the bundle file are processed. This code uses an API provided by the browser to create the CSS styles.

Comment: It does not create js code, it still creates a .css file. But it uses js to transform and bundle your css code and inject it into your .html file. So indeed, the loader uses javascript code which is executed when the contents of the bundle file are processed. But the end product is still css.

Answer (score 0):

Q1. **Why not webpack just get everything and bundle them into a single bundle.js file?**

This allows for lazy loading and code splitting that makes your application load fast.

Q2. **what's the purpose of 0.chunk.js, main.chunk.js?**

These are chunk which are named by webpack. They have JS code that is transpiled to work in older and newer browsers both.

Q3.**Who inserts the script elements for each js file in the index.html file, webpack, or loader?**

The tags are inserted by webpack. Webpack uses loaders for using non JS resources such as images and stylesheets etc.

Hope that helps